# Can we delete question 12796?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

[This Q was recently locked](https://askubuntu.com/q/12796/169736) even trough my best wishes of delete it. I mean, who cares about some petition for firms someone did several years ago and even so failed? This shouldn't be the kind of useful questions we should keep around.

Is a POLL, not even a question and the answers are not even better. Just a bunch of opinion chiming in and some links to some petitions that got the official response:

> At this point, **I ask that people no longer send in their requests** about adding support for Linux using the submission forms.

Why should we keep around something that we all know is not within Adobe interests?

Comment: I'd question how that question even *qualifies* as historically significant. Only 15 votes? **Only 720 views?** Pfft. Throw that in the trash can where it belongs. It's not even a question, it failed, and barely anyone ever even looks at it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hmm yes. That question has no particular value to the future visitors. I am deleting it.